# What is the simplest way to make a small low power and low price circuit that flashes LED's

Tags: microcontroller, avr, prototyping

I am wanting to make a small handheld circuit that could flash anywhere between 4-6 leds in a programmed order. It has to be as small as possible and use very little energy. I am trying to make these cheap enough that I can make a lot.

I was thinking about using one of the AVR series mcu.

Size wise I was thinking of having it run on triple A'S.  I am open to suggestions.

**Edit** I am looking for DIP MCUs not smd.

Comment: Consider a boost reg, like MCP1640 to convert 1.5V to 5V to run an MCU off.

Comment: Consider an MCU with a wide supply range and no regulator, with a battery that operates over that supply range.  If the intent is as cheap as it sounds like it is, just don't bother with regulator.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how programmable/complex your flashing is - you may be able to do it without software. In which case:

[Most Simple Stoplight circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/most-simple-stoplight-circuit)

[Blink an LED with just a capacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/blink-an-led-with-just-a-capacitor)

If you do need to use a microcontroller - with 6 I/O pins which is low power and small then I'd look at:

[MSP430 (Value Line)](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/mcu/valueline/index.shtml?DCMP=Value_Line&HQS=Other+BA+430value-promo). Here's an app note on [powering an MSP430 from a single cell (using a charge pump)](http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/slaa398/slaa398.pdf). There's also now an [MSP430 which runs at 0.9V](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Msp430l092?DCMP=MSP430™16-BITULTRA-LOWPOW+Other&HQS=Other+OT+lowvoltagewiki).

[AVR PicoPower](http://www.atmel.com/products/AVR/default_picopower.asp) is also worth a look. Even the ATMega168/328 used in Arduino though can be put into quite low power modes.

Here's a couple of Arduino libs to do it:

http://code.google.com/p/narcoleptic/

http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Enerlib

Comment: Find any through hole MCUs like those, that's what I need.

Comment: I'd go for the MSP430G2211. Here's a couple of my projects which might be relevant: http://blog.hodgepig.org/2010/09/12/577/ http://blog.hodgepig.org/2010/09/30/jam-jar-lamp/

Comment: What would you suggest using to power this? I want it to be a low profile and small as possible? Think 4 double A's would work good?

Comment: 4 x AA would be fine, but I'd go with 2 x 1.5v coin cells or a CR2 for 3v

Comment: Using a microcontroller for a simple LED sequencer seems like overkill. The most complex I'd go for would be a 555 timer driving a binary counter used to run through some of the address lines of a PROM/EPROM programmed with the required bit/LED patterns. By using switches on the higher address lines and putting the required patterns at the relevant locations in the (E)PROM you could even switch between patterns.

Comment: The [Atmel ATtiny43U](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?part_id=4523) has an integrated charge pump that runs down to 0.7 V and provides up to 30 mA (@ 1.0 V, 10 mA @ 0.7 V).  Alas, it is SMD only, but such is the price of high integration.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [MSP430G2231](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/MSP430G2231IN14/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvu0Nwh4cA1wRJeGVHRRTIMb5J5dZL4y5Q%3d)?
It's really low power and is pretty cheap too. Plus it isn't a SMD MCU.

Comment: I'd choose the cheaper MSP430G2211, unless you need the ADCs

Answer (score 1):

if you want cheap you dont even need a micro controller for simple on/off. Infact i would avoid them alltogether. a Simple sequence of leds that repeat you could use a simple 555 timer and a counter module, i cant think off which ones off the top of my head but there are lots of option and would take some time to plow through data sheets.

Comment: A favourite at school electronics clubs was a 4017 CMOS decade counter clocked by a 555 timer. The best variant I saw was with the 4017 being used as part of the resistor timing chain on a second 555 timer running in astable mode. By using the 4017 to switch between up to 10 variable resistors you could make a simple tone sequencer that drove everyone mad after a few minutes!

Answer (score 1):

You might also look at the MiniPOV.
It's the simplest, smallest, and lowest-cost way to flash LEDS with a microcontroller that I've ever seen.
But I'm sure you can find some way to "trim the fat" on this project :-).

- [MiniPOV 1](http://www.ladyada.net/make/minipov/)
- [MiniPOV v2](http://www.ladyada.net/make/minipov2/)
- [MiniPOV v3](http://www.ladyada.net/make/minipov3/) has a [parts list](http://www.ladyada.net/make/minipov3/parts.html) that links directly to a distributor of each part
- [MiniPOV discussion forum](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewforum.php?f=11)
- [MiniPOV 3 kit for sale](http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=5) -- note that this price does not include an outer case or batteries, which could easily double the materials cost of this item.

I've been told that lots of designers find it easier to make a new system when they can start with a "scaffolding" of a known-working system, even when they end up completely changing everything so there isn't any part of the scaffolding remaining.

Using a microcontroller for a simple LED sequencer seems like overkill, but any alternative I can think of requires more than 1 components to replace the 1 microcontroller chip -- and how can "more components" be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Throwie that blinks in Morse code?
[Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/LED-Throwie-Talkie/) and [Ward's own website](http://c2.com/cybords/?ComputerizedThrowie).
It uses an 8 pin DIP microcontroller
(less than $3 in ones).